# Any elegant way to parse camel-style string to upper case enum in java?

Tags: java, enums

I need to parse enum instance from string. The problem is that I have camel-style input string, e.g. `docType` and constant-style enum, e.g. `DOC_TYPE`.

As far as I know, java requires exactly matching on enum parsing, so I'm trying to find an elegant way to solve this problem.

Comment: I have two questions for you:  1) Are you sure the rules you suggest are consistent across all cases, so that inserting underscores before every upper-case letter and then upcasing the result would work?   and 2) why are you looking for "elegant" before you even have "working"?

Comment: Here's a hint: [Character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isUpperCase(char))

Answer (score 5):

Apache commons provides a handy utility method to split a camel-case string: [Apache commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html)

I have used this to do exactly what you require:

```
final String[] words = StringUtils.splitByCharacterTypeCamelCase(camelCase);
final String name = String.join("_", words).toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a static method in your enum that matches and returns enum entry value.

```
public enum SomeEnum {
    SOME_VALUE("someValue"),
    OTHER_VALUE("otherValue");

    private final String camelCaseValue;

    private static final SomeEnum[] values = values();

    SomeEnum(String camelCaseValue) {
        this.camelCaseValue = camelCaseValue;
    }

    public static SomeEnum fromCamelCase(String camelCaseValue) {
        for (SomeEnum value : values) {
            if(value.camelCaseValue.equals(camelCaseValue)) {
                return value;
            }
        }
        return SOME_VALUE;
    }
}
```

Of course, you don't have to return SOME_VALUE as the default one. You could return null or throw an exception if there is no match. If the mapping can be coded dynamically (e.g. remove underscores then compare case-insensitively) you don't even need to store the camelCaseValue field.

I just wanted to show the general idea behind having a static method to get the enum entry.

Comment: This is fine if he/she has control over the enum. However I disagree with you returning SOME_VALUE as the default for your method fromCamelCase. If the for loop does not return anything the method should return null or some other indicator that the string did not match any of the enum values.

Comment: I agree that this is the most "beautiful" way to have the enums and to retrieve them properly, but I would create a custom Exception to throw if the value that is given by parameters doesn't fit with any previously defined enum. To return a default value could be tricky to debug and maintain after some time.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I totally agree.